# Ackermann function versus n nested loops

Tags: python, computer-science, computability

I'm working my way thorugh a book on computation (Minksy 1967) and am having a hard time with relating a recursive function to a function defined in terms of loops.  Specifically he asks to find the relationship between two functions:

The Ackermann function (all code in python):

```
def a(n,m):
    if n==0:
        return m+1
    if m==0:
        return a(n-1,1)
    return a(n-1,a(n,m-1))
```

And a function that computes with n nested loops:

```
def p(n,m):
    for i_1 in range(m):
        for i_2 in range(m):
           ...
             for i_n in range(m):
                  m+=1
```

A recursive way of writing this (with one loop) is:

```
def p(n,m):
     if n==0:
         return m+1
     for i in range(m):
         m=p(n-1,m)
     return m
```

Or a fully recursive way to write it would be:

```
def p(n,m):
    return P(n,m,m)
def P(n,k,m):
    if n==0:
        return m+1
    if k==1:
        return P(n-1,m,m)
    m=P(n,k-1,m)
    return P(n-1,m,m)
```

Is there some simple way these two functions are related? I feel like I'm crawling around in a fog - any insight you could give me into how to approach these sorts of problems would be greatly appreciated.  Also, is there a way to implement the fully recursive loop function without the introduction of a third parameter?  Thanks.

Comment: In the first code snippet you have two consecutive `return` - a typo?

Comment: @eumiro, the second return is the case when m != 0 and n != 0

Comment: @Paul, OK, thanks, I fixed the code indenting.

Comment: "I'm crawling around in a fog" is just another word for "i'm writing a recursive function"...

Answer (score 1):

Uhm... I don't think this will help you much, I'm kinda baffled too, but here are my thoughts.

- Ackerman(0, m) == p(0, m)
- Ackerman(1, m + 1) == p(1, m)

edit -- wait I think I miscopied the function. I'll give this more thought later, and if I think of something I'll update!